# getting incoming call caller phone number on specific client in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, asterisk

could any one suggest how to get incoming call event in client computer which the call redirected to that extension.

When a call redirect an local extension I need to search my app db for caller phone if already called or not, If called I need to get caller information from db into my application page. I don't know more about asterisk how it works. What I need is getting incoming call caller phone number in specific client which the call redirected to that client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fop/fop2 (www.asternic.org) or write your own code for popup window

After that you can do url for your task.

For transfers you probably need write custom app. For that you need know well asterisk. So start with asterisk book. You can use ami events for get moment of call.

http://voip.rus.net/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Events